# Unable to pass Parameter from Button to Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass Parameters to Action Method But I am Unable to do it below is my button's code

```
<div class="button-wrapper"><div class="clearfix btn-topmarge">
 <div class=""><input id="btnApply" type="submit" name="Apply" value="Apply" 
 class="btn btn-crud" onclick="Reset()" />
 <input id="btnClear" type="reset" name="Clear" value="Clear" class="btn btn- 
  crud clear-btn" />
 <input id="btnExcel" type="button" name="Excel" value="Export To Excel" 
    class="btn btn-crud" 
   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportBookingToExcel","Bookings", new 
  {EmployeeIds = Model.EmployeeIds == null ? null : string.Join(",", 
  Model.EmployeeIds), ApprovalStatus = Model.ApprovalStatus == null ? null : 
  string.Join(",", Model.ApprovalStatus),fromDate = ViewBag.FromDate, toDate = 
  ViewBag.ToDate, depDate = ViewBag.DepDate,page = Model.PageNumber })'"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unable to do it" is not a good explanation of your problem. Does it have to be a javascript call (`location.href`) at all? If not, I would replace the whole *btnExcel* input with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export To Excel", "ExportBookingToExcel", "Bookings", new { EmployeeIds = Model.EmployeeIds == null ? null : string.Join(",", Model.EmployeeIds), ApprovalStatus = Model.ApprovalStatus == null ? null : string.Join(",", Model.ApprovalStatus), fromDate = ViewBag.FromDate, toDate = ViewBag.ToDate, depDate = ViewBag.DepDate, page = Model.PageNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-crud" })
```

by removing the javascript part (`onclick` attribute), you can ensure that it's not a JavaScript problem, and you can hover the Link and see if it was constructed correctly.

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation Actually my Requirement was I wanted to pass parameter to action method using button on same view but i was unable to do that

Comment: i am accepting your answer because it gave me hint to resolve my problem thanks you so much